# Problem with the limit of an expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

consider the following equation:

```
NF = 1.6;
df[dn_] = NF - dn;
DeltaF[mis_, theta_, 
   dn_] = (dn Tan[theta] Cot[ArcSin[mis Sin[theta]]] + df[dn])/NF;
```

If, for example, `mis` is fixed to 0.875 and `dn` to 0.1, I'm expecting this function to tend to 1 as theta approaches 0, with a singularity in theta=1. However, the limit gives this result:

```
Limit[DeltaF[0.875, theta, 0.1], theta -> 0]]
1.00893
```

If the precision is increased with `SetPrecision`, I get a bunch of number, but still far from what I'd expect. Is it mathematically correct or there something wrong with the precision here?
Basically, I'd like to plot this equation in a way I can see it going to 1 as theta goes to 0, with obviously the singularity in 0.Thanks.

Comment: Substituting exact rational numbers for your approximate ones, I get a value of exactly `113/112` for `theta=0`. So, I think your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Yes, which is the value I get. If you try to do it now by using the raw equation `(0.1 Tan[0] Cot[ArcSin[0.875 Sin[0]]] + 1.5)/1.6`, instead of calling `DeltaF[0.875, 0, 0.1]`, you'll get `Indeterminete`, as said. This makes sense, since it goes to 0*Infinite. Why that?

Comment: It's because you used `=` to define `DeltaF`, thereby symbolically evaluating the formula in the definition.This reduces `Tan[theta] Cot[ArcSin[mis Sin[theta]]]` to `(Sec[theta] Sqrt[1 - mis^2 Sin[theta]^2])/mis`, thus removing the removable singularity. If you substitute numbers before evaluation, it doesn't do that.

Comment: All right, I didn't notice that. Thanks for spotting! Effectively, simplifying the equation it is possible to get something without singularity. I though that, since the equation could be reduced to something similar to `Tan[x] Cot[x]` as `x->0`, the whole equation was going to 1, but actually it's not.